# List maven dependencies only used during test case run

Tags: java, maven

Can list out the maven dependencies only used during test.

For example: mvn dependency:list

But only ones for test run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn dependency:list` by default list dependencies with scope test.

This means that you will see dependencies needed for test.
For executing tests you need all your project dependencies.

On list you see scope for each listed dependencies, like:

```
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.2.5:provided
...
[INFO]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.5.0:compile
...
[INFO]    junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
```

You can [include](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html#includeScope) specific dependency scope, or [exclude](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/list-mojo.html#excludeScope) some of them.